# Delete files from android obb folder every 5 minutes in background

Tags: java, android, apk, background-task

**I want to make an app which stays in the background (even if removed from Recent Apps) and keeps deleting the file as soon as it is back or every 5 minute.**

I tried using

```java
File dir = new File("PATH");
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
```

The file is in the `Android\obb\com.example.example` folder

but it stops as soon as the app is removed from the Recent apps, I have seen apps staying in the background but dont really know how to do that

Comment: read about job scheduler though min time is 15mins , u can create alarm manager but make sure to conside doze mode and standby mode

Comment: hi, thanks for commenting, i managed to make a service, but how will i delete the file?? (from the service)

Comment: `public void deleteImages() {
        File dir = new File(PATH);
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            if (!(children.length == 0)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }`